# accuracy shunt resistor beter than 0.1%?

Tags: resistors, shunt, accuracy

I want to make a circuit that can measure a current more accurate then 0.1%. For instance if I measure 7A, I want to be able to read 7.000 A. If I use a 0.1% shunt resistor I do not know if it is 7.007A or 6.993A it can be +/- 7mA. I did take a look at some big stores and the best shunts they sell are 0.1% accurate with a price about 5 or 6Eu a piece. How can I get a better accuracy? Can I even go further like 6 digits? What is possible?

thank you for the help!

Comment: Unfortunately shopping questions are off topic here. My recommendation is to search on digikey, mouser, element14/Farnell and use their search functions to search for shunts with the desired tolerance.

Comment: Well I did that and they are not there, thats why I wrote I did already take a look at some big stores.  So now I ask here. So if they are not there maybe people use more of the 0.1% resistors together or measure the real resistance and compensate for the error. But that is just a gamble and I want to know for sure.

Comment: There are 0.01% resistors. Search for: precision current sense resistors. They are about 50 dollars. For accurate resistors, as far as I know, they are tuned with extra resistors. If you want to measure the current that accurate, you also need to good voltage reference.

Comment: You would need to go to a precision device such as found at http://vpgsensors.com/ - depending on the resistive value of the device, very precise layout techniques may be necessary.

Answer (score 4):

You should expect to have to apply your own calibration to build instrumentation to this sort of level - you can't just expect to put a bunch of bits together and achieve fantastic precision/accuracy.

You will probably find some fairly simple slope-and-offset linear calibration is all you need for this case, though ammeter shunts can be tricky beasts.  For a start you need to make sure you are definitely measuring the voltage across the shunt, and not seeing a lot of ground lift happening elsewhere in the circuit.

Also think about the temperature coefficient of the shunt resistor - you might find the accuracy of your reading depends on how long the load's been turned on for...

Answer (score 2):

In theory you can get some of following approaches to get better accuracy:

- select from more shunts, th 0.1% accuracy means, that any of these is somewhere in 99.9%-100.1% range, but does not ensure where exactly. By testing more of them you cen find by chance one, that is exactly the value you need (or any given close range od it)
- carefully combine more shunts together - if you use one wicht is 99.9% and another one, which is 100.1% (both half value) in serie, you get 200%.0 of the half value (means 100% of wanted value). Similarry you can combine them in parallel or make even more complicated net. Depends of what values you have, you cen get much close to what you want.
- recalculate the result - if you have 99.9% and measure it preciselly, then you can simply divide the result with 99.9% to get exact value (either digitally, if you have something digital on the way, or redraw the analog scale to show the right values) - by the way you can create the scale on blank background from scratch based on your own calibration process

You can combine all above methods to get better results with what you actually have.

---

Practically you will run to problems with stability, reliability and reproduceability - to have exact values you need exactly controlled environment as there is thermal change in all parameters, also radio noise can come to way, earth magnetic field (and all others), local gravity, etc, etc, so you cannot get infinite precision by changing just one piece of you equipement, you would need more stable environment for better precision, the more numbers, the (exponentially) more complicated and expensive stabilisation is needed.

Comment: Okay I understand that, but is it not easier / cheaper to add a trim potentiometer in the differential op-amp circuit which amplifies the shunt voltage? And take a shunt that is bigger so it will not get that hot and your resistance will not change too much because of the changing temperature? Or measure the temperature of the shunt and compensate for the changed resistance at a different temperature?

Comment: Of course you can vary the gain of your amplifier. But how will you know if it's accurate?

Comment: @Want2Know: yes, you can do that and can do more things to have more accurate result. I just pointed out, that the more accuracy you need, the harder it is to get it and the cost rose too. And you also need to ensure, what your results are, so some more precise calibration must be done too. Just getting one part with one better parameter is usually not enought to get more VALID digits. But if you can build expensive laboratorry, you can get near to one particle precision. Just it would cost millions and millions $$. So as everything else, there si some tradof you need to solve for yourself.

Answer (score 2):

The easiest approach to very high accuracy is to buy a fairly accurate and *extremely stable* resistor that is of roughly the correct value.

Then, use a calibration setup of known and acceptable error to provide a known current (or currents) and adjust your circuit so it reads more accurately. This is best done digitally. The simplest calibration, if you are confident there is negligible offset voltage, is to multiply your ADC reading by a scale factor. This will also cancel out initial error in your ADC voltage reference and any other linear error sources in your circuit.

Current measurement with ppm-level accuracy is possible but you will not achieve it on your first or second try unless you go out and spend big $$ on an instrument, and even then it will be transistory.

Answer (score 2):

Beware of the temperature coefficient of copper.
Over 100 degree Centigrade change, the resistance will change 40%.
Over 1 degree, that is 0.4%.

This becomes important in OpAmp circuits using non-inverting circuits, where the feedback current must exit to "Ground" and return to the power supply.
As current varies, because Vout varies, the localized ground foil changes temperature.

With the standard copper foil thickness --- 1 ounce of CU per square foot --- being 35 microns or 1.4 mils (0.0014 inches), and electrical resistance being 0.00050 (500 microOhms per square), with Thermal Resistance of 70 degree Cent per watt per square, you have a Thermal design issue. Get a quadrille pad and draw lots of squares, thinking about current flows and heat flows.

Learn to think about thermal shorts and thermal opens & isothermal systems.